# How can i create single feature fwith Combining Selected feature qgis?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, features

I am trying to create a single Qgsfeature from the Combination of selected features in Pyqgis.
Currently i create the feature using a loop over selected features and combine them 1 by 1.
but this process froze qgis UI.
does anyone can suggest me another idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your desired resulting geometry is a Multigeometry feature (MultiPoint, MultiLineString, MultiPolygon), the result of the union of the selected features.

You can use the combine function (= Union):

```py
# start with an empty geometry
multi =QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY')
# union the selected features with multi
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
     multi = multi.combine(feature.geometry())
```

and the result is a Multigeometry Qgsfeature